# Change Document Root and SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, hosting, web-hosting

I have a business cloud hosting account with Hostgator. I am working with an add-on domain that has an ssl cert. Just out of curiosity, I am about to push out a new version of the site, can I change the document root of the website without negatively effecting the SSL cert?

(I understand I will have to move, or copy the cert(.txt) file in document root to the new document root.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can push new site without any problem but make sure that you have wildcard SSL is yes then not an issue but if you have Positve SSL means only for root domain not for sub domain, then it will work only for a domain that you configured in SSL cert file